# How to enable ManipulationDelta event outside of ScrollViewer in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I wrote a xaml with a scrollviewer, and the scrollviewer is replaced inside a frame. I want to register the ManipulationDelta event for the frame, but I failed. If that is possible to register ManipulationDelta event outside of the scrollviewer control in windows phone 8?

```
<Grid>
    <Frame ManipulationDelta="Frame_ManipulationDelta">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel>
                <ListView x:Name="List">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <ListView x:Name="List2">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `failed`? is it that the Frame does not fire `ManipulationDelta` event at all?

Comment: @kennyzx Frame doesn't fire the ManipulationDelta event at all, it looks like the internal control already handled the event and stop raising it up.

Comment: @imJustice Did you try applying breakpoints?

Comment: Have you tried using "UseOptimizedManipulationRouting" property.

Comment: the code is not recognized in windows phone project, did you incorrectly tag your question?

Comment: @VictoryJessie I am not able to set the UseOptimizedManipulationRouting to my control. My target platform is windows phone 8.1, is that a problem?

Comment: @kennyzx my target platform is windows phone 8.1, and I'm using visual studio 2013 express.

Comment: @Kulasangar I tried, as I mentioned, it looks the internal control in lower level already interrupt the ManipulationDelta event.

Comment: @imJustice then i should tag as wp8.1. `Frame` is not available in wp8.

Comment: Maybe check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/834b497e-36c7-4122-8c5b-6e3bb8640ae5/handle-manipulation-events-for-controls-in-a-scrollviewer?forum=wpf) out? It seems that you may have to have the ScrollViewer not handle the manipulation events in the way that it does by default, which will require a custom implementation like the one described. You may also be able to simply call `e.Handled=false;` after `base.OnManipulationDelta` finishes.